# Searching Names and phonenumbers

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-arrays

mine is homework question in response to the previous Question i posted on this site:

i redid the code to the following:

```
    import re
    people = ["Karen", "Peter", "Joan", "Joe", "Carmen", "Nancy", "Kevin"]

    phonenumbers = ["201-222-2222", "201-555-1212", "201-967-1490", 201-333-3333",'201-725-3444", "201-555-1222", "201-444-4656"]

name = raw_input("Enter person's name:")

found = false
for i in range(0, len(people)):

   value = people[i]
   m = ("(" + name + ".*)",value)

   if m:
       found = True
       print (people[i], phonenumber[i])
   else:
       print ("No matching name was found.")
```

My question is how do i tell the program to check if Karen's phone number is the 201-222-2222? And Yes this is a homework assignment. I changed the names and the phone numbers in my acutal program.

When i run this program and type any character all the names and phone number show up that's where i'm having difficutly...

Comment: Please title your question something related to the question, not related to how urgent your homework is.

Comment: you know about dictionary??

Comment: I don't know about dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: Question isn't clear to me.

The following code my help.

1.) First it ask for name then check if it exist in the people list.
2.) Then if it exist it saves it in variable called abc.
3.) After loop is finished it prints the abc which is the name you entered and that person phone number.

```
import re
people = ["Karen", "Peter", "Joan", "Joe", "Carmen", "Nancy", "Kevin"]

phonenumbers = ["201-222-2222", "201-555-1212", "201-967-1490", "201-333-3333","201-725-3444", "201-555-1222", "201-444-4656"]

name = input("Enter person's name:")
abc = "" # Will store the name and phone number
found = False 
for i in range(0, len(people)):
   if people[i].lower() == name.lower(): #checks if input name match + use method to lower all char
          abc = people[i]+" Has the number "+phonenumbers[i]
   value = people[i]
   m = ("(" + name + ".*)",value)
   if m:
       found = True
       print (people[i], phonenumbers[i]) # missing letter "s"
   else:
       print ("No matching name was found.")

print("\n"+abc)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me where and what the correct code would be please.. To check other people's phone number like for example if I type Karen it should show Karen

Comment: For me I had to edit the m: code to work and thanks for all that helped me out